# remove duplicates from array String without set

Tags: java, arrays

So I have String array that looks like this:

```
arraySubs:

math
math
math
web
web
web
prog
prog
prog
```

Now I want to remove the duplicates to look like this:

```
arraySubs:

math
web
prog
```

I wouldn't mind if there is null on places that should be removed, so I tried this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < arraySubs.length; j++) {
    if(j<arraySubs.length-1) {
        if(arraySubs[j+1]==arraySubs[j]) {//equalsIgnoreCase doesn't work.
            arraySubs[j]=null;
        }   
    }
    if(arraySubs[j]!=null) {
        System.out.println(arraySubs[j]);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work it's still printing all of them, any ideas?
I don't wanna use Set, HashSet etc. Or any other tools such as iterators.
equals() doesn't work...

Comment: Don't compare Strings with `==`

Comment: why do you want to inhibit yourself too much?  Can you loop and add to a List if it does not exist?  Or even append to a String with a delimiter and then check for the existence?

Comment: You only ever compare each item against exactly one other. You need to add an inner loop for searching.

Comment: (A) Do you know that the array is ordered? (B) Why `equalsIgnoreCase` doesn't work? What is the output you get in this case?

Comment: This is actually a good example on when to use ArrayLists. It would save you a lot of unncessary trouble in that case

Comment: @RoeeGavirel (A)Yes,(B) I caught nullPointerException....

Comment: @GhostCat its not duplicate question, equals doesn't help, please remove the mark for dupicates.

Comment: @DusanMartinovicFit then you have other problem, `==` for strings definitely wouldn't work.

Comment: @GhostCat , I edited my code , so now it shows problem with equals(), is this good?

Comment: Don't get frustrated ... but now your question is a DUP of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) question. And beyond that: dont put up *parts* of your code. Instead - read [mcve] and give *clear* descriptions of expected and actual output. But still: you are dealing with *very basic* problems. And this community is not a free tutor service where you get taught such basic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `arraySubs[j+1]==arraySubs[j]` you compare instances ids rather then value. You should use `arraySubs[j+1].equals(arraySubs[j])`

Just try to debug your code, or run something like:

```
for(int j = 0; j < arraySubs.length; j++) {
    if(j<arraySubs.length-1) {
        System.out.println("j:" + j);
        System.out.println("j val:" + arraySubs[j]);
        System.out.println("j+1 val:" + arraySubs[j+1]);
        if(arraySubs[j+1] != null && arraySubs[j+1].equalsIgnoreCase(arraySubs[j])) { // The FIX
            System.out.println("j val changed to null");
            arraySubs[j]=null;
        }   
    }
    if(arraySubs[j]!=null) {
        System.out.println(arraySubs[j]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("skipping null");
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work... tried it

Comment: @DusanMartinovicFit What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it print all values? none? run-time exception?

Comment: I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` for some reason

Comment: @DusanMartinovicFit So you probably "null"ing an object and try to reach it. Try to run the example code I put here and see how far can you get.

Comment: Still `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @DusanMartinovicFit well, you probably have already nulls in the `arraySubs`, don't you? In this case you have to validate that `arraySubs[j+1]` is not null before calling the `.equals` function. See the edited code.

Comment: Yes this actually works, I was missing `arraySubs[j+1] != null` , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use `set` you can use `stream`:

```
list.stream()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But still, using set will be the most efficient and clear.

Comment: Thanks! It's good way and it works , but wanted to use a different code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stream` with `collect`. This way, you will even be able to maintain the counts for each element, e.g.:

```
String[] array = new String[]{"math", "math", "web"};
Map<String, Long> items = Arrays.stream(array)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(items);
System.out.println(items.keySet());
```

Comment: Thanks, I found my answer , but this is good as well!